# Mathematica: do the same thing for several files (Import, Take, ...)

Tags: file, automation, wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

I'm currently working on handling some experimental data with Mathematica.

I have several files that I basically want to do the same thing with. At the moment, I just copy and paste everything and change the filenames, which looks like this:

```
rechn1 = Import[
   "/path/4He.H2O.MeV14460.ddd.gd.dat", "Table"];
r1 = Length[rechn1];
rechn1a = Take[rechn1, {9, r1}];
plotr1 = ListPlot[rechn1a]

rechn2 = Import[
   "/path/4He.H2O.MeV15000.ddd.gd.dat", "Table"];
r2 = Length[rechn2];
rechn2a = Take[rechn2, {9, r2}];
plotr2 = ListPlot[rechn2a]

rechn3 = Import[
   "/path/4He.H2O.MeV15670.ddd.gd.dat", "Table"];
r3 = Length[rechn3];
rechn3a = Take[rechn3, {9, r3}];
plotr3 = ListPlot[rechn3a]
```

and so on.
I'm not especially well versed in Mathematica, so this to me seemed like a good option. Copy, paste, change a few numbers.

However, I now have to handle even more data like this. So, is there any way to tell Mathematica to handle all files a certain way? And maybe also to change just a few details? For example, handle everything the same, but have a different PlotStyle or title for the plots?

It would be great to find a way to automate this process a bit, since I have a lot of files to handle now and copy and pasting just isn't an option any more.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual with Mathematica there is a variety of ways to do what you want.  Here are some pieces you may be able to assemble into a solution which works for you.

You could replace your sequence of 4 function invocations with a composition of them all, like this:

```
ListPlot[Drop[Import["/path/4He.H2O.MeV15670.ddd.gd.dat", "Table"], 9]]
```

This is initially a lot harder to interpret (for you, Mathematica won't have a problem) but it will be easier to use in what follows, and it will avoid cluttering up your workspace with unnecessary temporary variables.  Note that I've replaced your `Take[expr,{9,Length[expr]}]` with the equivalent `Drop[expr,8]` to avoid having to call `Length` on the imported data file.

Now we can tidy this up into a function, such as:

```
makePlot[fn_String] := ListPlot[Drop[Import[fn, "Table"], 8]]
```

Next, lets get all the filenames you need.  I suppose that your current working directory is the parent of "/path" and that the call

```
hefiles = FileNames["4He.*.ddd.gd.dat", {"*"}, Infinity];
```

will return a list of the names of all your input files.  Let's modify the `makePlot` function for reasons which will become obvious in a moment:

```
makePlot[ix_Integer, fn_String] := myPlots[ix] = ListPlot[Drop[Import[fn, "Table"], 9]];
```

Now, you can write

```
Do[makePlot[i,heFiles[[i]]],{i,1,Length[heFiles}]
```

and this ought, if I've got the syntax right and matched up all the brackets, to make all your plots with one statement.  They will now be stored as `myPlots[1], myPlots[2], ...`.

If you want to set options for your `ListPlot` command simply amend the definition of `makePlot` to something like

```
makePlot[fn_String] := ListPlot[Drop[Import[fn, "Table"], 8],plotOption-> setting, plotOption2->setting2]
```

or, if you want to make leaps and bounds in your Mathematica knowledge, investigate the `Options` function and you can modify `makePlot` to take options as (optional) arguments and pass them through to `ListPlot`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It never even occurred to me to define a function. Now I'm just wondering about the FileNames command. For some reason it doesn't show the files that are in my current work directory (let's call it datadirectory), I have to move one directory up, then they are listed as /datadirectory/filename  Is there any way around this? The parent directory also has other directories in it that contain filenames that are similar, but that I don't want to plot.

Comment: `FileNames[]` should return the names of the files in Mathematica's current working directory, just like `FileNames["*"]`.  I suggest you fiddle around until you figure it out.

Comment: assuming the notebook is in the directory with the files do SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]